# How to correctly type annotation in F# list of tuple

Tags: f#

```
let rec matchs  list =
    if list = [] then []
    else
        let hd :: tl = list 
        if fst hd.[0] = "A" 
            then hd:: matchs tl
            else matchs tl
```

I am getting error FS0752: The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type constraints on the line :

```
if fst hd.[0] = "A"
```

I tried different ways of changing the parameter and list types but issue is still not fixed.
I would want to test my function with this line

```
Matchs [("A",5); ("BB",6); ("AA",9); ("A",0)];;
```

My function would compare a string to the first tuple element string and add the second element to new list then return list at the end, but so far i am stuck on this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an aside, this problem really is a perfect fit for pattern matching. You can replace both of the `if` conditions in your snippet with a single `match` that uses nested pattern to identify tuples where the first element is the string `"A"`:

```
let rec matchs list =
  match list with 
  | [] -> []
  | ("A", _) as hd :: tl -> hd :: matchs tl
  | _::tl -> matchs tl
```

The pattern `("A", _) as hd :: tl` means that you want things that are list cons cells (`_ :: _`) where you want to name the first element `hd` so that you can refer to it later (`_ as hd`) and it should be a tuple where the first thing is a string `"A"` (`"A", _`).

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the non idiomatic code you need to put paren around `(fst hd)`, also `.[]` index seqences and not tuples. So you are trying to do two things.

So the correct if statement would be `(fst hd) = "A"`

Since reinventing List.filter sounds like a school assigntment I will stop here.